# Using Docker for JBOSS EAP and Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, jboss, docker, redhat

To better manage the promotion of builds in my project, I was looking out on how to use docker.

Our application contains jboss EAP, war files which has the application UI and logic, some property files and a set of application configurations stored in a separate schema of the DB.

Is it possible to create a container with
1. JBOSS EAP
2. Property Files
3. WAR files
4. Oracle Tables (along with data)?

I have tried with the first 3 and successful in it. I am not sure how to create a container which has the Oracle tables along with its data (records in the tables).

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Docker is not a virtualization platform supported by Oracle.

I successfully completed this "checklist" from Frits Hoogland Weblog:

[Installing the Oracle database in docker](https://fritshoogland.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/installing-the-oracle-database-in-docker/)

This article is written against Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.7, surely it will work on Redhat and similar.

Regards
Giovanni

https://fritshoogland.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/installing-the-oracle-database-in-docker/